# Best way to save source line information in an ANTLR4.7.1 lexer/parser

Tags: antlr, antlr4

All,

I'm fairly new to antlr so the solution may be trivial, however the solution escapes me. (I have much experience with parsers and scanners, just not with ANTLR generated ones.)

I'm recoding an assembler for a 32-bit (National Series 32000) CPU. It originally was coded using C++/(f)lex/yacc/bison, but is being ported to Java8. Part of my requirements is that I produce a listing file that contains addresses, generated code, source line, etc.

I have an object that can contain all of the information I need (e.g source line, generated code, etc) and I would like to associate said object with each token. My question is:

1) What is the best way to capture a source line? I considered using the lexer (+ modes) to capture a source line, but found no way to capture a source line and reject (or push back) the input to make it available for subsequent processing. I know that CharStream buffers it's entire input stream in one fell swoop. Would subclassing CharStream to construct my container and capture source line contents be an appropriate approach?

2) How to associate my container object with each token? I suspect subclassing Token and creating a custom TokenFactory is required, but am uncertain how to connect a custom CharStream to Token. (This is why I liked the concept of using the lexer to capture individual lines.)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not sure about v4, but ANTLR v3's `CommonToken` has `line` and `charPositionInLine` fields that are filled in by lexer for all emitted tokens.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to capture position information manually. Each token (which is normally an instance of [CommonToken](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/CommonToken.java) comes with [line](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/CommonToken.java#L29) and [char offset](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/CommonToken.java#L35) values, plus a few more like the token index (which is the index of the token in the token stream) and start/stop indices, which give you the character indexes in the original text input.

The resulting parse tree also contains references to the token or symbol that make up a rule context or terminal node. So you can look up positions at any time, always connected to a particular parser rule.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Mike. Sadly, I need access to the entire source line when generating the assembler listing file.

Comment: That doesn't make the approach invalid. You have all positioning informations at hand. You can go up in the parse tree to find a surrounding context that covers a line, or take the token index from a token within such a line and examine the token stream around that index to find the entire line.